# Page Load Animation Jitters then Begins

Tags: css, animation, webkit

I am trying to create a really subtle entrance animation for one of my websites. The animations are working but when the website loads it looks really janky and flashes the content that will appear, then it smooths out and works correctly.

http://parkinsonbuildinggroup.flywheelsites.com

I am using a web builder but this part is custom coded. Might be a problem with the way the site builder loads things?

```
@keyframes fadeInScale {
  0% {
    transform: scale(1.5);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(1.0);
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@keyframes fadeIn {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@keyframes slideDown {
  0% {
    transform: translateY(-100%);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateY(0%);
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

#_header_row-3-17{
  animation: 1s ease-in-out 2s 1 slideDown both;
}
div_block-16-18{
  animation: 1.5s ease-in-out 1s 1 fadeInScale both;
}
section-2-8 {
  background-image:radial-gradient(1000px 750px ellipse at 25% 50%, 
  rgba(0,0,0,.8), rgba(0,0,0,0)), 
  url("http://parkinsonbuildinggroup.flywheelsites.com/wp- 
  content/uploads/2019/04/BAX_4684-Recovered-1.jpg");
  background-size:cover;
  animation: 1s ease-in-out 0s 1 fadeIn both;
}
```

I want the site to load very smoothly picture>text>header but for some reason it stutters at first and I just can't seem to find out why.

Comment: Try removing the 1 from all the animation classes. So 1s ease-in-out 2s 1 slideDown both; would become  animation: 1s ease-in-out 2s slideDown both;

Comment: Tried, no improvment